# The Polynomials $P_n(x+y)$

Tags: polynomials, summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Let $$\displaystyle P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k.$$

We need to show that $$P_n(x+y) = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}P_k(x)y^{n-k}.$$
In the proof, we have $$\begin{array}{rcl}
P_n(x+y) &=& \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(x+y)^k\\
&=& \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}x^iy^{k-i}\\
&=& \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i}x^iy^{k-i}.
\end{array}$$
What to do next knowing that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}P_k(x)y^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i}x^iy^{n-k}?$

Comment: question is, is it not allowed to use $P_{n}(x)=(1+x)^{n}$ ?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Actually, it is true that $P_n(x) = (1 + x)^n$. If it can aid the proof then maybe we can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we already know that $P_{n}(x)=(1+x)^{n}$ then it is straightforward

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{n}(x+y)&=((1+x)+y)^{n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}(1+x)^{k}y^{n-k}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}P_{k}(x)y^{n-k}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you @RezhaAdrianTanuharja.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some hints on how I would prove the equality that you need to show. First prove that $$P_{n+1}(x) = (1+x) \cdot P_n(x).$$ You can show this directly.

With that equality in the bag we can prove your main equality with induction. So suppose that it is true for $n$. Then 
\begin{align*}
P_{n+1}(x+y) &= (1+x+y) \cdot P_n(x+y) \\
&= (1+x+y) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} P_k(x) y^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\left[ \binom{n}{k} (1+x) P_k(x) y^{n-k} + \binom{n}{k} P_k(x) y^{n+1-k}\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\left[ \binom{n}{k} P_{k+1}(x) y^{n-k} + \binom{n}{k} P_k(x) y^{n+1-k}\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\left(\binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}\right) P_{k}(x) y^{n+1-k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k} P_{k}(x) y^{n+1-k}.
\end{align*}
This is what you wanted to show. I will let you fill in the details on some of these equalities yourself. And don't forget the base case.

Comment: Thank you @Pjotr5.